# Java and String as parameter in method

Tags: java, string, methods

i need to pass a String to a method, but it doesn't work...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Enter a String:");
    String abd = Input.readString();

    long number = number(String abd);
    System.out.println(number);

}
public static long number(String abd){
    long num= 0;

    if(abd == "AAA"){
        num = 100L;
    }
    if(abd == "BB"){
        ean2 = 20L;
    }

    return ean2;
```

it prints 0 for the number...and i dont know why! i need to do this with a String...i know it would work with char...is there some way to make this work with String?

Comment: Change `long number = number(String abd);` to `long number = number( abd);`. While passing arguments, you don't have to mention the type. And then look  at the question used to mark this as a duplicate

Comment: thank you for your fast response! but unfortunatly that doesn't change the problem!

Comment: Did you change `==` to `.equals()`?. Also, you probably need an `else if` instead of `if` in the `"abd.equals("BB")` check

Comment: Use `.euals()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus.